# laravel one to many relationships returning null

Tags: database, null, foreign-keys, relationship, laravel-5.6

there are two models.product and image 
**In My product model:**

```
// one to many   relationship with images table 
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\image');
}
```

**Image Model**

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\product');


}
```

**ProductController**

```
public function productDetail($slug)
{
    $product = product::where([
      ['slug',$slug],
      ['seller_id' ,Auth::id()],
    ])->first();
    //$storagePath = Storage::get(['images']);
    //get the image of that product 
    //$image   = asset('storage/product_images'.$product->images);



    if($product)
    {
      $image    = Storage::url($product->images); // give the image path from product table

      //give images from the image table 
      $product_image   = \App\product::find(11)->images;
         $arr = array();

          foreach(\App\product::find($product->id)->images() as $i)
          {
            array($arr,$i->image);
          }

          dd($arr);  // problem returning always null 






      return view('backEnd.seller.product_detail',compact('product','image')); 
    }
```

**Problem Statement:**
 In my controller when i tried to get all the images of specific product i am getting **Null** . I am trying to solve this for one day ago.please help me Which i am missing?

**image table migration**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('product_id');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**product table migration**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('seller_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
        $table->string('product');
        $table->text('discription');
        $table->string('type')->nullable();
        $table->date('date');
        $table->string('images');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->integer('sold_qty')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Note:**
  I have make sure that in my image table there are 5 records of product_id 11.Please help Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the relation in your database. You can do it by adding this to your image migration:

```
$table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('product');
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your model names are `Product` and `Image`.

Please check whether below change will give you what you want...

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Image');
```

note that model name starts with uppercase letter and,

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
```

and database constraint as @steve-trap mentioned is not necessary. Anyway it will introduce a constraint so that you cannot add image for non-existing product.

Then in controller:

```
foreach (App\Product::find($product->id)->images as $image) {
    $arr[] = $image->image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I solved this problem by:**

1. Changed the model names to uppercase.
2. Changed the product table column name images to cover.
3. Changed the method images() to pictures in Product Model

**Conclusion:**
   If you use the column name then don't use that column name for building relationship.
and always write model name that starts with uppercase.